# Appium saying install libimobiledevice but terminal says already installed

Tags: ios, appium, device

I am trying to run Appium on a real iOS device.  In the logs I get the following error:

> The 'idevice_id' program is not installed. If you are running a real
>   device test it is necessary. Install with 'brew install
>   libimobiledevice --HEAD.

I then run brew install libimobiledevice --HEAD in the terminal and get the following warning:

> libimobiledevice HEAD-5a85432_2 is already installed

Anyone know a way around this infinite loop of warnings?

Comment: Did you try unlinking and linking it again?

Comment: Try the following commands and see if it works

```brew uninstall ideviceinstaller, 
brew uninstall libimobiledevice, 
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice, 
brew link --overwrite libimobiledevice, 
brew install ideviceinstaller, 
brew link --overwrite ideviceinstaller```

Comment: Still getting the same error after following these exact commands unfortunately.

Comment: in the terminal do you get output for `which idevice_id` ?

Comment: what is your environment? IDE, Java, ... etc

Comment: @CharlieSeligman, any update on the question?

Comment: nope.. installed on a different machine. all working on that machine.

Comment: You didn't tell if `which idevice_id` works in the machine with problem?

Answer (score 1):

Go to terminal and type

> brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice

This will work!